# unwanted vim cscope search autocompletion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, cscope

I'm using `cscope` in `vim` to find files, symbols & call in my codebase and it'c incredibly helpful. However, I have realized the following:

Sometimes "suddenly" (choice of word is for lack of better understanding of origin of effect) the cscope query seems to insert a file name when I type `:cs f` the filename is inserted after I hit `<space>` when I intended to type `:cs f s symbol` for example the command ends up like:`:cs f filename.c s symbol` and the only way, that I know, to get around it, is to restart vim. How do I disable this undesired autocompletion and how did it get enabled at first?

Comment: Is `cs:` a typo? To check some other things: run `verbose cabbrev` and `:verbose cmap` to see if anything has mapped f in that way.

Comment: Hoops yes `cs:` is a typo - i fixed that :$

Comment: Have you tried the other commands i mentioned?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I'm not in that mode right now, when I'll havwe to come back to this when it happens again.... sorry...